# xcodebuild command crashed from extension assets

Tags: swift, xcode, assets, xcodebuild, fastlane

When I run a build using fastlane or xcodebuild, I get an error:

```
"The following build commands failed:
  Compile As set Catalog /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Intermediate Build Files Path/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/LotteriesWidget.appex .../ LotteriesWidget/Resources/Assets.xcassets"
```

Assets.xcassets Location set in "Relative to Group", changing this setting produces no results.

This error exists if **Assets.xcassets** are Copy Bundle Resources for my Today Extension. If you move them to the application target, the build and archiving succeeds, but the resources are not displayed.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Just to make sure: did you try to delete DerivedData folder?

Comment: After each Fastlane run script performs a full clean of the project with DerivedData cleanup